# Проблема с отображением данных в excel

Tags: php, excel

Имеется 20-значники который формируется  из файла в excel вот такие: 10101000200000943001
в сформированном excel файле показывает 1,01018E+19. в чём может быть проблема! сам 20-значник string. формат ячеек пишет общий, если его конвертировать в числовой то последние 5 чисел превращаются в нуль.

Comment: Что за библиотека для генерации?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение со стилями! я как говорил экспортирую как таблицу html через header.
Кому ни будь может и пригодиться!
header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset:UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");

//и стили
<style>
     br {
         mso-data-placement:same-cell;
     }
     .style0 {
        mso-number-format:General;
        white-space:nowrap;
        mso-style-id:0;
    }
    td {
        mso-style-parent:style0;
        mso-number-format:"@";
        text-align: left;
    }
    td.date {
        mso-number-format:"dd.mm.yyyy";
    }
    td.time {
        mso-number-format:"[h]:mm:ss";
    }
    .number {
        mso-number-format:"0";
    }
</style>  всё работает супер

Answer (score 0):

Правой клавишей на ячейке формат ячейки нужно поставить текстовый....